# While loop not able to handle the value ten

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is supposed to give out destiny number for a name. It gives the correct results for all the other user inputs. However, if the user name's destiny number comes out to 10, the output is 10 instead of 1. The while loop is supposed to do that. I tried to skirt it by putting a print statement but it still doesn't work. Where is it going wrong?

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
name = input("Please Enter Your Full Name Without Spaces in between: ")
if name.isalpha():
    name1 = name.upper()
    initsum = 0
    d = {'A':1,
    'B':2,
    'C':3,
    'D':4,
    'E':5,
    'F':8,
    'G':3,
    'H':5,
    'I':1,
    'J':1,
    'K':2,
    'L':3,
    'M':4,
    'N':5,
    'O':7,
    'P':8,
    'Q':1,
    'R':2,
    'S':3,
    'T':4,
    'U':6,
    'V':6,
    'W':6,
    'X':5,
    'Y':1,
    'Z':7}
    name2 = list(name1)
    initsum = 0
    for chr in name2:
        initsum += d[chr]
    if initsum == 10:
        print("Your destiny number is 1")
    else:
        check = str(initsum)
        if len(check)>1:
            tot=0
            while(initsum>0):
                dig=initsum%10
                tot=tot+dig
                initsum=initsum//10
            print("Your destiny number is", tot)
        else:
            print("Your destiny number is", initsum)
else:
    print("Name is invalid")
```

Comment: Do you mean that `print("Your destiny number is 1")` never executes?

Comment: @JonClements Yes.

Comment: I entered "abcd" and got result 1 and not 10.

Comment: Even if you enter a name of "BP" ?

Comment: The code you've provided when entering "abcd" works just fine...

Comment: @JonClements try the name abhishekrai

Comment: But `initsum` won't be 10 will it? It'll be 28 - so that block will never execute...

Comment: @Aryerez abcd is not a name. Try "abhishekrai" ..which is when I realized there is a problem.

Comment: @JonClements so the len(check)>1 won't kick in?

Comment: It will but then you do other stuff... put some print statements inside your loops to show what variables are at each stage... then you'll notice where your logic is leading to an unexpected result...

Comment: @Aryerez I meant to say that when the user input is a long name, that's when the problem arose. No offense meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over complicating this function in too many ways. A simple example of the same thing would be:

```
name = input("Please Enter Your Full Name Without Spaces in between: ")
destiny = sum(d[char] for char in name.upper())
while len(str(destiny)) > 1:
    destiny = sum(int(x) for x in str(destiny))
```

If you're unfamiliar with `sum` (or if you want a longer more readable version) it is basically the same as doing this:

```
name = input("Please Enter Your Full Name Without Spaces in between: ")
destiny = 0
for char in name.upper():
    destiny += d[char]
while len(str(destiny)) > 1:
    tmp = destiny
    destiny = 0
    for char in str(tmp):
        destiny += int(char)
```

Comment: Think you've also slightly over-complicated it... You might as well avoid that while(len(...)) check and do `destiny = sum(int(c) for c in str(destiny))` and be done with it.

Comment: @JonClements This might be true but i wanted to handle (the unlikely case) that the sum would also be double-digits

Comment: This works. Mine is complicated because I am just starting out and am not too familiar with the steps in your program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @OferSadan In case of a long name like Scarlett Johannesson the sum will be double digit. That was the issue to begin with.

Comment: @MuhammadIsmail i figured, that's why you don't need to check for something being equal to `10` at all. Thanks for accepting the answer, feel free to upvote it as well if you think it's good

Comment: @OferSadan I have less than 15 rep. So it won't reflect. I did the check for 10, just to bypass the whole thing. The only problem came when the destiny number equaled 10. It works fine even for Scarlett Johannesson otherwise. :)